# Call variable in CURL Command

Tags: shell, curl, rundeck

I am trying to define a variable for a curl command.

```
curl --location -k --request GET 'https://myprojt.test9.abc.com/api/part/config=8594&select=parts,Action,refernceNumber&SalesID=333&partNumber=789-635'
```

I want to call a variable for `&partNumber=789-635`

Tried defining `$part='@option.partnumber@'`,  this is the input parameter which takes a value.

```
curl --location -k --request GET 'https://myprojt.test9.abc.com/api/part/config=8594&select=parts,Action,refernceNumber&SalesID=333&partNumber=$part'
```

I even tried replacing single quotes (') by double (") but not working, kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign directly like `MYVAR=@option.myoption@`

I leave a working example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='myoption' value='world' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>e781836f-e0f8-4ccb-b03f-a384be306860</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobInlineScript</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# starting
MYVAR=@option.myoption@

# print
echo "hello $MYVAR"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>e781836f-e0f8-4ccb-b03f-a384be306860</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUyfk.jpg) the result.